# Why Druid segments become unavailable after data ingestion

Tags: segment, druid

Druid cluster shows unavailable for certain segments of data of data source after data ingestion.
Ex: **72.4% available (2352 segments, 647 segments unavailable)**
We have a clustered deployment 3 nodes :
master node (coordinator amd overlord)
Data node (historical and middlemanager)
Query node (broker and router)
Any specific reason why it is happening so.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is resolved after clean restart of master and data nodes. However just restarting nodes without cleaning data did not work

Comment: Hello! Could you please explain what is a _clean restart of master and data nodes_? Thanks in advance

Comment: Deletion of segments-cache data and indexing logs in data and master nodes

Comment: but isn't this going make druid lose data?

Comment: Since the data would be in deep storage it will be able to load the segments